# Altium - create a mirror image of a board

Tags: altium, layout

I want to create an identical motor drive board in the right and left sides.  I just finished layout for the right side and I am wondering what is the easiest way to create the mirror image of this board for the left side?

For example: the connectors on the "top" side would now be on the bottom of the other board.  All components and tracks will also switch sides, layer stack will be inverted, etc.  Is there any command sequence in Altium that will do this without me having to manually re-assign everything to the other layer?

Comment: Why not simply have two boards made and flip over the second one?

Comment: The board is not at all symmetrical, so using the same board and just flipping it over won't fit.  Moreover, there are several tall components (connectors, large caps) that need to be towards the inside of the robot.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. While the general layout is conceptually "mirrorable" at a high level, many of the individual components are not. You'll have to lay out a mirror image board as a separate project.

Comment: He's asking about moving components to the other side of the board, not mirroring them physically. I think "mirror" was a poor word choice on his part

Comment: @DerStrom8: Yes, I suppose that's one way to get there, but you still have the problem of how the routing of signals to the non-symmetrical components changes. You also have to think about the mechanical details, such as transistors and/or ICs connected to heatsinks, routing of cables, etc.

Comment: If the components are simply moving to the other side of the board, I guess I don't know why he can't just flip the whole thing over =P

Comment: @DerStrom8: He can, but then all of the components are on the bottom! Probably not what he had in mind.

Comment: In his original post: *"So, for example, the connectors on the "top" side would now be on the bottom of the other board. All components and tracks will also switch sides"*

Comment: @DerStrom8: Yes, that's exactly what the "mirror" command in a PCB layout program does. If you then flip *that* board over, you get a mirror-image layout, but with the components now on top, like the original board.

Comment: I never said he should use the "mirror" command. I said he should just flip the board over.

Comment: I think the OP needs to provide a little more detail about what he expects to do. Some representative and reference pictures would definitely be nice

Comment: @DerStrom8: No, the original intent was clear enough, and I thought that your first comment indicated that you understood, but now it seems that you have missed the point. He's proposing to take a copy of a PCB layout and "mirror" all of the components individually. They will stay in place, but move to the opposite side of the board. If you then flip that board over, you get a mirror-image layout with the components on top. *My* point is that you can't just do the same thing to the traces -- the connections to certain asymmetric components will need to be rerouted.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I agree with your statement, but that's not what it sounded like he was asking. That's why I asked for a clearer description of what he's planning to do. I will sit on the sidelines and wait for more information before posting again

Comment: Does Altium flip traces too, then create a shortcut key (edit-cmd) to flip over Yaxis then select all as if to drag, hold mouse then hotkey and cross your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

You can select, copy, paste, and flip layers with "L", and it will flip it exactly like you want.

However the problem is, if you duplicate the components on the board, they are no longer linked to the schematic sheet, and if you duplicate the schematic sheet, then update the board, it'll just add your new components in a corner like it always does and you have to place them.

There's a "[multi channel](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Multi-Channel+Design+Concepts)" feature in Altium, I've never used it, but supposedly it does what you want.

There's also [this hack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgdCJ1rbNnA) that looks nice.

Or if you don't have many components you can do it by hand.

Once you have duplicated the schematic sheet and the component placement on the board, copy all the tracks and vias from the first one. Use one of the selection tools like "include only tracks and vias", no need to click click click. Paste the traces on the second block, and they will all inherit the nets from the pads you pasted them on. This is quite convenient.

Then, select the second block, drag it, and flip it to the other side with "L".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Select entire board (crtl-A)
2. Click somewhere within the selection and hold (or drag)
3. Press "Y" to mirror vertically (or "X" to mirror horizontally)
4. Click again to place the now mirrored board

This worked pretty well for me when I needed to create an identical, vertically-mirrored copy of a board I designed, but I noticed a few problems it caused that I later corrected manually

1. My component 3D models go messed up (either they moved off the pad, or the flipped upside down so that they were inside the board. I fixed this by individually selecting each component, re-mirroring them, and placing them in the exact same spot (the vertically orientated component then go misaligned with the net, so I had to rotate them 180 afterwards).
2. Overlay text was mirrored and unreadable. I went in and re-mirrored them and sometime rotated them.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for when you said "mirror", but its what I was looking for when I found this page, so maybe this will help someone.